# smart code autocomplete for netbeans

Tags: netbeans

There is some plugin for netbeans 7 to make code autocomplete smart like Sublime Text 2 ? , for example when i type :

```
inpos
```

it will generate :

```
$this->input->post('someparam');
```

I did some google search but nothing found.

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: What you are asking for, is "zen-coding" just google it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this very easily by following these steps.

**1.** Go to **Tools** then click **Options**.

**2.** A new window pops up.

**3.** Under **Editor** section , select the **Code Template** tab.

**4.** Now you will see various options like **Language** , **Template** etc...

**5.** Under **Template** option, you can define your own abbreviations like your **inpos**

**6.** For your **inops** , define the text you want to show on expansion under the **Expanded Text** area like your **$this->input->post('someparam');**

**7.** Now click **OK**.

Now write your abbreviation on the editor and press **Tab** to get your code.(You can set another key for this and other options as well).

Comment: Thank you, but i have a question :  how we can make this automatically ? , ( like Sublime Text 2 which i can do this directly )

Comment: @NabilLem How do you do it automatically in Sublime Text...?